# ModelResetter RAII Object

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qt4, qabstractitemmodel

I have a custom proxy model that occasionally overhauls itself when a new column/row is added to its source model. From the docs it appears that calling [QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel)  and [QAbstractItemModel::endResetModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel) at the beginning and end of such an operation is the proper methodology. My overhaul function, unfortunately, has several possible exit points and I just know that I'll forget to call `endResetModel` at every exit point as it gets more complex.

Therefore, I'd like to create a simple RAII class that will call `beginResetModel` upon construction and then call `endResetModel` upon destruction, like follows:

```
class ModelResetter
{
public:
    ModelResetter(QAbstractItemModel* model) : m_model(model)
    {
        m_model->beginResetModel();
    }
    ~ModelResetter()
    {
        m_model->endResetModel();
    }

private:
    QAbstractItemModel* m_model;
};
```

The problem is that `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` are both `protected` in `QAbstractItemModel`. Declaring `ModelResetter` as a `friend class` in my **inherited** model doesn't appear to help, since I'm trying to interact with the base class.

I'd rather not do a custom implementation for every model I implement, so can I do this with templates? I'm not very familiar with template syntax yet.

**Edit 1:** (I removed the sample template code in Edit 2 to avoid confusion)

It'd be nice if I could somehow restrict the template to only allow types that inherit `QAbstractItemModel`, but I don't see anything in standard C++ that allows that. I will not use Boost.

**Edit 2**: I guess I wasn't really clear about my requirements. Here they are:

- Operates on the base class for the general case
- Enforces the `QAbstractItemModel` inheritance requirement while in debug mode without penalty in release mode
- Simple usage with almost no overhead
- Requires no modification of the base class or new functions

Comment: This is basically the opposite situation of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767525/friendness-and-derived-class). Note that `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` are not `virtual` in the base implementation, so I can't take advantage of that.

Comment: Inherit `ModelResetter` from `QAsbtractItemModel` too :D

Comment: Clever, but doesn't that violate pretty much every rule for the `is-a` idea of inheritance?

Comment: maybe you could make your ModelResetter a nested class in your model. Then you can use protected methods

Comment: I was considering that option. I'd prefer to write it more generically, though.

Comment: See my edit for an example of a templated implementation. I don't fully understand templates yet, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but after a couple days I put together a template-based solution that fulfills all of my requirements. Yay for my first from-scratch template class. Here's the implementation:

```
//modelresetter.h
#include <QAbstractItemModel>

/* you must declare this class as a friend to your model
 * to give it access to protected members as follows:
 * template <class Model> friend class ModelResetter;
 */
template<class Model>
class ModelResetter
{
public:
    ModelResetter(Model* model) : m_model(model)
    {
        Q_ASSERT_X(qobject_cast<QAbstractItemModel*>(model) != 0, __FUNCTION__,
                   "templated object does not inherit QAbstractItemModel");
        m_model->beginResetModel();
    }
    ~ModelResetter()
    {
        m_model->endResetModel();
    }

private:
    Model* m_model;
};
```

and usage:

```
//mymodel.cpp
bool MyModel::overhaul()
{
    ModelResetter<MyModel> resetter(this); resetter;  //prevent compiler warning

    //do stuff
    if(somethingswrong)
        return false; //model will finish reset at every exit point

    //do more stuff
    return true; //model also completes reset on success
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you could have your inherited model expose methods that would just call beginResetModel() and endResetModel() respectively, then have ModelResetter call those methods.

Comment: Is there then no way for me to write the ModelResetter class such that it uses the standard implementation of the qt model base class?

Comment: is your inherited model publicly inherited?

Comment: does http://pastebin.com/NFuHpB8c compile for you? it does for me on clang.  If it does, then it seems like you could make ModelResetter a friend of MyModel, then call beginResetModel() directly... Do you have an error message of it not working?

Comment: Yes, that compiles. However, following your example, I'd prefer to implement `class Op` it in a more generalized manner such that it accepts a `Base*` and I can apply it to other models, not just the one that I have implemented at the moment.

Comment: can you make a wrapper for Base whose sole purpose is exporting the required function for Op?  Then have all required Derived siblings extend from that wrapper.